# Ratio of areas under the curve of polynomials in an interval

Tags: definite-integrals, proof-explanation, intuition, area

Let $g(x)=\dfrac{\int_0^xs^2ds}{\int_0^ns^2ds}$, and let $f(x)=\dfrac{\int_x^ns^2ds}{\int_0^ns^2ds}$. Note that $g(x)+f(x)=1$. Let $v=\{x:f(x)=g(x)\}$, which is just going to be a number and only depends on the numerator since $f(x),g(x)$ have exactly the same denominator. Then I am interested in the quantity $\alpha(n)=\dfrac{v}{n}$.

One can explicitly calculate $v$ (I use $x$ as variable) in terms of $n$. That yields the equation:

$$2x^3-6nx^2+6n^2x=n^3$$

which after plotting it [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/90mzjxyqrm), we can see it's just a line, namely $v=\beta n$, then $\alpha(n)=\beta$.

That can be confirmed here in this [animation](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hqo4t1sau0). Furthermore, after playing with the animation, if instead of $\int x^2dx$ I consider $\int x^3dx$, the result still holds, namely $\alpha(n)=K$ is just some constant.

This defies my intuition, because I first I assumed the bigger the $n$, the bigger the $\alpha$, in other words, I thought $v$ grew than faster than $\beta n$, but apparently it doesn't.

My questions are:

1. I think my analysis is correct, but I'd appreciate if someone can point out any mistake.
2. Is there a more general result that deals with this? some theorem that says this is true for all polynomials or something like that?
3. My intuition failed me, but is there another way where one can see this without going through all the analysis? in other words, a perspective that makes this fact more straightforward to see?

Edit:
The equation I had was wrong. The actual equation is $2x^3=n^3$, as pointed out by @Andrei.

Comment: Your equation is wrong. It should be $2x^3=n^3$. In more general case, when you integrate $s^p$, you should get $2x^{p+1}=n^{p+1}$. In a way this is similar to the lily pad doubling area problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2429872/a-lily-pad-doubles-in-area-every-second-after-one-minute-it-fills-the-pond-ho

Comment: Thanks. That answers my first question and to some degree my second question. However, as I said, that seems counterintuitive to me. Do you by any chance have a point of view, under which this behavior is more straightforward to see?

Comment: It's just a question of scaling. You scale the $x$ axis by some factor $k$. The $y$ axis scales as $k^p$. Then the area scales as $k^{p+1}$. You are doing the inverse problem: you want to scale the area by a factor $k$. That means $x$ scales as $k^\frac1{p+1}$ and $y$ scales as $k^\frac p{p+1}$. This scaling is independent of the area